# Read XML with Arabic data embedded c#

Tags: c#, utf-8, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I am trying to load an XML file that contains a mix of ASCII text and Arabic characters. Here is the top snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="ar_EG">
<context>
    <message>
        <location filename="ui/aboutdialog.cpp" line="90"/>
        <source>You have </source>
        <translation type="unfinished">يوجد لديك</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="ui/aboutdialog.cpp" line="90"/>
        <source> launches left</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">عدد التشغيلات المتبقية</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

I want to load this up into a C# TreeView object, but I am having issues with loading into XDocument or XMLDocument.

Using this:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(File.ReadAllText(tbxTSFileName.Text));
```

or

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(File.ReadAllText(tbxTSFileName.Text, Encoding.GetEncoding(874)));
```

Gives me a "Invalid URI: Uri string is too long" error.

Using this:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(tbxTSFileName.Text);
```

Gives the error "Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 9 position 40".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for the method you're calling.

`XDocument.Load` takes a URL, not an XML string.

You want `XDocument.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Your reader needs to use utf-8, as indicated in the document itself. Ideally, you would use an XML reader and it would take care of using the indicated encoding itself.